# How to prove that if $y\in B(x_{0},\delta)$ then $y\in B(0,1)$?

Tags: general-topology, inequality, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove this simple inclusion:

$B(x_{0},\delta) \subset B(0,1)$ with $\delta=\frac{1-||x_{0}||}{12}$

I know that I should suppose that $y\in B(x_{0},\delta)$ then $y\in B(0,1)$.

Which equals to showing that if $||x_{0}-y|| < \frac{1-||x_{0}||}{12}$ then $||y||<1$. I tried using the fact that $y= y -x_{0}+x_{0}$, but to no avail. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I'm guessing $||x_0||<1$?

Comment: @carmichael561 Yes, that's correct.

Comment: $\lVert y\rVert \leqslant \lVert y-x_0\rVert + \lVert x_0\rVert$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea: if $||y-x_0||<\delta=\frac{1-||x_0||}{12}$, then
$$ ||y||\leq ||x_0||+||y-x_0||<||x_0||+\frac{1-||x_0||}{12}=\frac{1+11||x_0||}{12}<\frac{1+11}{12}=1 $$